# Counter Strike Condition Zero Mac Dedicated Server with Steam

Tags: steam, macos, hosting, counter-strike

I just purchased counter strike condition zero from steam, and now I want to host a public server over which my friends can connect from different places over the internet.

For that I tried installing Half Life Dedicated Server from steam itself, but when I run it all I see is this error
[image]

Have any of you guys got any luck with running public servers from your mac for counter strike condition zero?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: While I could be wrong, I don't believe that Valve made OSX versions of the dedicated server software for hlds (Half-Life based games) or srcds (Half-Life 2 based games).

Comment: Valve's Alfred Reynolds said this on their [Github bug tracker](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/halflife/issues/353) in 2013: "The demand is too low to warrant the cost of supporting the OS X for the dedicated server, and Apple's recent trend of removing higher end hardware support from their options just compounds the price premium you already pay, making running a dedicated server on OSX a bad idea."

Comment: mac is a trouble to work with in games as it is let alone running servers on them